# BBC slider works even if javascript off, how they do that?

Tags: javascript, slider

BBC slider works even if javascript off, how they do that? http://www.bbc.co.uk/ - you will see that it still works if you turn off javascript

Thanks

Comment: What slider are you talking about? If you mean the carousel, it doesn't work for me with JS off.

Comment: If you mean the big one with the arrows left and right, no it doesn't. (It's no longer a slider/carousel, just links with a hover CSS class.)

Comment: hm, seems some caching, thnak you

Comment: It doesn't work for me when JS is off, on Safari 5.1.2 for Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're using *progressive enhancement*. The left and right arrows on the main carousel are normal links with a CSS hover class:

```
<a id="dz-arrow-previous" href="?dzf=default&amp;focusedpane=center">...</a>
<a id="dz-arrow-next" href="?dzf=default&amp;focusedpane=left">...</a>
```

If JavaScript isn't enabled, clicking them moves you to the next page by following the link (without a sliding effect, at least on Chrome; CSS transitions could probably be used). If JavaScript is enabled, they hook clicks on the elements and do the nifty carousel thing.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing clever going on - it just falls back to sending a request to the server if Javascript is unavailable. If you click a link with Javascript unavailable, you're effectively getting a new page from the server - watch the URL change as you do it.